W10 command line prevent process launch failure due to "blocked" redirect files
I have a .vbs file which runs a .bat file which has the following line in it:
python src\core\start.py 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt

... annoyingly, after I shut down a previous run and ordered the .vbs to run again, I got this:
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
Although there was no obvious process which was the culprit (I couldn't for example immediately see any python process), it turned out that stdout.txt or stderr.txt were "the culprits". When I did the following command instead:
python src\core\start.py 1> stdout2.txt 2> stderr2.txt

... the application ran fine. To double-check that this was the issue, later I opened "stderr2.txt" in Notepad++ and tried that command again: "The process cannot...".
Is there any way to say "redirect output to a file, but if you can't, just ignore that fact and at least run the Fine program anyway"? I mean, either in the command line, or somehow by passing some directive in the .bat file?

I don't see any difference between those two commands.  Did you copy and paste the incorrect command?

He added a "2" to the filenames to test if the first set of handles were still open.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/

also, does the vbs exit between execution or does it remain running between batch file calls? If it continues, does the problem persist if you exit the vbs and then run it again? I don't think file handles are held open in batch files; IIRC devices like lpt or nul are held open till reboot (or cmd window session closure?) So the VBA wrapper might be the issue

@Yorik In fact the VBS file is (I think) irrelevant. Because this phenomenon I'm describing happens even if I just run the .bat file, or even if I just manually run the CLI command in the Terminal (CMD window). I mentioned VBS because it occurred to me that there might be a technique in VBS to prevent this (I know nothing whatsoever about VBS). I'm now inclining to think I might just run a Python helper file, with subprocess.run(...). Python can function as an OS command file (i.e. substitute for BASH/.bat files) in its own right.

As mentioned in a comment, I know very little about VBS, and not much about the scrabbly W10 .bat command "language", and I'm always inclined to reach for Python as a "Swiss army knife" solution whenever and wherever.
In my development location I want output to go to the terminal, but in my production location, which will have a directory "operative" in its path, I want stdout to go to a file called stdout.txt and stderr to go to a file called stderr.txt. However, since one of my first steps in any run is to set up proper logging, it isn't that important, and the discovery that stdout.txt is busy in another process certainly should not stop the run. So something like this:
import subprocess, pathlib, sys

if 'operative' in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
    completed_process = subprocess.run(r'start_ve.bat && python src/core/start.py', 
        shell=True, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True)
    if completed_process.stdout == None:
        print('\n\n*** problem capturing stdout')
    else:
        with open('stdout.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(completed_process.stdout)
    if completed_process.stderr == None:
        print('\n\n*** problem capturing stderr')
    else:
        with open('stderr.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(completed_process.stderr)
    sys.exit()

subprocess.run(r'start_ve.bat && python src/core/start.py', shell=True)

... if things do indeed fail before logging is configured, it is nice to see clues about what went wrong in the output to stdout and stderr, so a more sophisticated version would actually use a loop with different names (stdout2.txt, stdout3.txt, etc.) in the eventuality that f.write(...) raises an exception.
However, in fact my experiments show that if stderr.txt is open in Notepad++, for example, f.write(...) in the above will NOT in fact fail: the file will still be overwritten despite being "owned by another process". Which, as I don't want my application to fail stupidly, is preferable in this case (for me).
NB This should also work in *nix OSs.
